# How do I make the Circle Avatar's location static so that it does not change while entering text into a form?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

This code of Forget password and I use `Stack` with 2 Containers and circle Avatar above of them.

At the beginning of the program, everything is fine, but when I fill out the form. Circle avatar goes down. How do I fix that?

Is the use of margin the reason for this, but how do I put the circuit avatar in the middle?

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';

import 'Login.dart';

class Restartpassword extends StatelessWidget {
  const Restartpassword({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.2),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Center(
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    height: 400,
                ),
                Center(
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                     height: 300,
                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                         border: Border.all(
                             width: 1,
                             color: Colors.grey
                         )
                     ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center ,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          //----------------------------------------------------
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.1),
                              border: Border(
                                left: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple,width: 10),
                              ),
                            ),
                            //----------------------------------------------------
                            width: 300,
                            height: 50,
                            //----------
                            child:TextFormField(
                              style: GoogleFonts.pacifico(
                                color: Colors.purple,
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                              ),
                              //----------------------------------
                              keyboardType:TextInputType.text ,
                              //----------------------------------
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter some text';
                                }
                                return null;
                              },
                              //-----------------------------------
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_open_sharp,color:Colors.purple),
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: '***New Password***',
                                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.pacifico(
                                    color: Colors.black54,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                ),
                                fillColor: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.2),
                                filled: true,

                                //-----------------------------------

                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          //----------------------------------------------------
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.1),
                              border: Border(
                                left: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepPurple,width: 10),
                              ),
                            ),
                            //----------------------------------------------------
                            width: 300,
                            height: 50,
                            //----------
                            child:TextFormField(
                              style: GoogleFonts.pacifico(
                                color: Colors.purple,
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                              ),
                              //----------------------------------
                              keyboardType:TextInputType.text ,
                              //----------------------------------
                              validator: (value) {
                                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                  return 'Please enter some text';
                                }
                                return null;
                              },
                              //-----------------------------------
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.lock_outline,color:Colors.purple),
                                border: InputBorder.none,
                                hintText: '***Confirm Password***',
                                hintStyle: GoogleFonts.pacifico(
                                    color: Colors.black54,
                                    fontSize: 15,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                ),
                                fillColor: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.2),
                                filled: true,

                                //-----------------------------------

                              ),
                            )),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Container(
                          width:130 ,
                          height: 45,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)
                          ),
                          child: MaterialButton(
                            minWidth: 130,
                              hoverColor: Colors.purple,
                              color: Colors.green,
                              onPressed: (){
                                Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loginScreen())) ;
                              },
                              child: Text('Restart '
                                ,style: GoogleFonts.pacifico(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize: 20.0,
                                ),
                              )),
                        )
                      ],

                    ),

              ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 80,
                  margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                    start: 165,
                        top: 210
                  ),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor:Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                    radius: 30,
                    child: Icon(Icons.lock,size: 60,
                    color: Colors.purple,),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: like this]

Comment: can you include that you are trying to build

Comment: I want to create a forget password Screen

Comment: OK but how would UI will look like

Comment: A container with a border, and on the border the Circle Avatar icon, and inside the container a form

Comment: hi yeasin , can you see the last my question ..please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `Stack` to the `Container` with the fields and then use [`Transform.translate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Transform/Transform.translate.html) to move the icon outside the border. This way the avatar circle is going to be fixed relative to the container.

Check the result (also [live on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=def1323d32dfbc4554fa2d6c10a2fe9f))

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Restartpassword(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class Restartpassword extends StatelessWidget {
  const Restartpassword({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Container(
        color: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.2),
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
            height: 300,
            decoration:
                BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          //----------------------------------------------------
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.1),
                            border: const Border(
                              left: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.deepPurple, width: 10),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //----------------------------------------------------
                          width: 300,
                          height: 50,
                          //----------
                          child: TextFormField(
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.purple,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                            ),
                            //----------------------------------
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            //----------------------------------
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Please enter some text';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            //-----------------------------------
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock_open_sharp,
                                  color: Colors.purple),
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: '***New Password***',
                              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              fillColor: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.2),
                              filled: true,

                              //-----------------------------------
                            ),
                          )),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                          //----------------------------------------------------
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.deepPurple.withOpacity(0.1),
                            border: const Border(
                              left: BorderSide(
                                  color: Colors.deepPurple, width: 10),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //----------------------------------------------------
                          width: 300,
                          height: 50,
                          //----------
                          child: TextFormField(
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.purple,
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                            ),
                            //----------------------------------
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                            //----------------------------------
                            validator: (value) {
                              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                return 'Please enter some text';
                              }
                              return null;
                            },
                            //-----------------------------------
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.lock_outline,
                                  color: Colors.purple),
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: '***Confirm Password***',
                              hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black54,
                                  fontSize: 15,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              fillColor: Colors.black12.withOpacity(0.2),
                              filled: true,

                              //-----------------------------------
                            ),
                          )),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: 130,
                        height: 45,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15)),
                        child: MaterialButton(
                            minWidth: 130,
                            hoverColor: Colors.purple,
                            color: Colors.green,
                            onPressed: () {
                              // Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => loginScreen())) ;
                            },
                            child: const Text(
                              'Restart ',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontSize: 20.0,
                              ),
                            )),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Transform.translate(
                  offset: const Offset(0, -40),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: SizedBox(
                      height: 80,
                      width: 80,
                      // margin: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 165, top: 210),
                      child: CircleAvatar(
                        backgroundColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.3),
                        radius: 30,
                        child: const Icon(
                          Icons.lock,
                          size: 60,
                          color: Colors.purple,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```